# Spring Cloud Contract YAML header matching

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

While creating a new resource using `POST` method, location of the new resource is added to response as `Location` header.

How to create a spring-cloud-contract YML to verify that response contains `Location` header with a valid `URI` as it's value?

**I tried with below YAML, but it doesn't work.**

```
request:
  method: POST
  url: /customers/v1
  body:
    firstName: First Name
    lastName: Last Name
    dateOfBirth: "1990-12-12"
    active: false
  headers:
    Content-Type: application/json
response:
  status: 201
  matchers:
    headers:
      - key: Location
        regex: "http://localhost/customers/v1/*"
```

**Generated code for test**

```
@Test
public void validate_create_customer_successfully() throws Exception {
    // given:
        MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body("{\"firstName\":\"First Name\",\"lastName\":\"Last Name\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"1990-12-12\",\"active\":false}");

    // when:
        ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                    .post("/customers/v1");

    // then:
        assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(201);
}
```

Generated code doesn't contain any header validation.

Comment: Which version of spring cloud contract are you using? Please check if the latest available ga version works

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I am using **2.2.1.RELEASE**. My repository is accessible [here](https://github.com/sudhirtumati/customer-service) for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below yaml definition works

```
response:
  status: 201
  headers:
      Location: "http://localhost/customers/v1/"
  matchers:
    headers:
      - key: Location
        regex: "http://localhost/customers/v1/.*"
```

**Generated code for test**

```
// then:
    assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(201);
    assertThat(response.header("Location")).matches("http://localhost/customers/v1/.*");
```

This works as expected. I don't know why. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Ah, yes. I could have pointed you to that, but I thought you wanted to verify any valid url and needed the predefined url pattern. The difference is that in your question you used the predefined regex pattern for url provided spring cloud contract. However, apparantly this isn't supported for header as we concluded. Now however, you are providing your own regex, which is supported for headers, which does not match any and all url's, but your specific url, with any possible addition.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested it out, but what happens if you try:

```
response:
  status: 201
  matchers:
    headers:
      - key: Location
        type: by_regex
        predefined: url
```

This is what you would use for your body matchers, I'm not sure if it will work for headers.

Just so you are aware. I believe the matchers section is only for the benefit of the testing side of the response (validating the response sent out by the producer). If you also want to supply this header as a stub response for your consumer, you will have to add it outside the matchers section as well with a fixed value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. `type: by_regex` results in an error that prevents from relevant test case being generated. I tried with `regexType: as_string`, but the output is still the same.

Comment: That is unfortunate, than it is probably not supported in the header section. If you use groovy dsl instead of yaml, I know you have the possibility to define custom functions producer response validation: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/2.1.x/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#_executing_custom_methods_on_the_server_side 

This would allow you to define a function in your test base that could then utilize Pattern URL = UrlHelper.URL. But these custom functions are not supported in yaml dsl.

Comment: Thank you again for the suggestion. The link you mentioned helped me to understand it better and pushed me to search further. Finally [this example](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_yaml/src/test/resources/contracts/beer/rest/shouldGrantABeerIfOldEnough.yml) showed me a new option and that worked